# unique value to id attribute in angular for a radio button

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button

I need to set a unique id for each radio button. This same button is repeated 4 times in same form .

(field 1 :  first two radio choices, field 2: next 2 radio chocies

Am trying to set a unique value for id, but failing to do so.

Needed:  [id]="g.name - g.id"

Tried :  [id] ="{{'g.name'+ g.id}}

**Radio button HTML :**

```
 <div *ngFor="let g of groups">
     <input type="radio" 
            [name]="g.name"  
            [id]="g.name"   <!-- expected id="g.name+g.id" -->
            [value]="option.value"                      
            [(ngModel)]="radioModel[groupId]" 
            [checked]="option.selected"/>
     <label [for]="option.name">{{option.name}}
 </div>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try to use row index and use that index in the id attribute.

```js
<div *ngFor="let g of groups;let i =index;">
     <input type="radio" 
            [name]="g.name"  
            [id]="i"   <!-- expected id="g.name+g.id" -->
            [value]="option.value"                      
            [(ngModel)]="radioModel[groupId]" 
            [checked]="option.selected"/>
     <label [for]="option.name">{{option.name}}
 </div>
```

your groups array contains 1 row or 4 rows?

Comment: Total two fields/rows. First field has two radio buttons, say male female. Another field so has same tow radio buttons. So want to differentiate all of them based on id

Comment: Ok, means your groups array like this : group:[{id:1,name:'male'},{id:2,name:'female'}] and you want to bind this two times(4 times radiobutton)?

Comment: Yes. group with id 1 should have one gender selection and group with id 2 would have another like you had { group1: male , group2: female } .  With your approach of [id]="index" , I would have  group 1 as id for first row radio buttons,  and group 2 as id for second radio buttons.  So I would need concatenate something with the index too like [id]="index + 'group.name". But am failing to concatenate.

Comment: Let me create a working sample for this. Update you in some time.

Comment: please check the example on this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rasqzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html . Please let me know if any inputs required.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of these two bindings is what you are trying to do:

```
[id]="g.name + g.id"         <!-- No separation between g.name and g.id -->
[id]="g.name + '-' + g.id"   <!-- g.name and g.id separated with a dash -->
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng4-loading-spinner-h6eak8) for a demo.

Comment: for some reason doesn't work with mine. Will plugin my custom code into stackblitz and try

Comment: You can also check in the console to see if there are errors when running your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make your radio button id like this

```html
[id]="{{g.name + g.id + 'radio1'}}"   <!-- expected id="g.name+g.id" -->
```

for next radio button use 'radio2' which will make each radio button id different

Comment: That code is evaluated in an `*ngFor`; there is no opportunity to "use 'radio2'".